# How to prove that $\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}\le \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

It is known that $$a_n,\ b_n\ge0.$$ And they are both upper bounded.
Knowing this how can one prove that $$\sup\{a_nb_n|n\in N\}\le \sup\{a_n|n\in N\}\sup\{b_n|n\in N\}$$ 
I don't see how to approach this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Notice $0 \leq a_n \leq \sup a_n $ and $0 \leq b_n \leq \sup b_n $. Hence,

$$ a_n b_n \leq \sup a_n \cdot \sup b_n $$

Hence, $\sup a_n \cdot \sup b_n$ is an upper bound of $\{ a_n b_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and therefore ...

Comment: Thanks how do I explain the conclusion of your 2nd line? Is it a sentence?

Comment: If $a \leq b $ and $c \leq d $ then $  ac \leq bd$. Since  for every $n \in \mathbb N $,  $ a_n \leq sup a_n $ and $ b_n \leq sup b_n $ then, $\forall n \in \mathbb N a_nb_n \leq sup a_n sup_b$